# Angular 5 How to detect that we are in production inside the index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

In my index.html, I do inline some external css by doing :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/external-material.css" />
```

In production mode, I'd like to include `external-material.min.css`

Is there a way to detech that I am in production mode inside my index.html ?

Comment: everything outside of `<app-root></app-root>` is not really part of the app. You should avoid loading your styles in the index.html

Comment: I recommend you alwas using the min version. If its a file that you are editing create a task that builds the min for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, even though I don't recommend it.

In your environment files that are used for production, add this

```
window.onload = () => window['isProductionModeEnabled'] = true;
```

In your `index.html` file, you can now do what you want with that value bound to your window.

Comment: this should work but this is a workaround. The better way would be to load the styles inside of the components and check there if its prod or not

Comment: @messerbill you can't check in your css files if the app is in production mode. And if you do it in the decorator, you will still need this workaround. And lastly, you need to rely on workarounds if you want to change the style sheets in the index file, because it isn't in the Angular context.

Comment: @messerbill and while it might seem useless, if you have heavy files, this could have some advantages, while putting it in the components will use the styles into the bundles.

Comment: "  because it isn't in the Angular context." - this is why i said that this is a workaround. Of course you cannot change the style inside of the component during the runtime, but on bundling. I do not see any benefits for a stylesheet loading that way. Those "heavy files" would have been downloaded anyway so where is the advantage here? Please give me an example if possible

Comment: If you have no `link` tag in your head for your styles, and you check at startup if it is in production mode, you can chose to load either of your style instead of both. Again, this might seem useless, but I'm just answering a question (and I stated I did not recommend it first).

Comment: `Again, this might seem useless, but I'm just answering a question` - you are right. +1